# No method 'val' in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an HTML form

```
<div class="field"> 
  <label for="num1">Number 1</label> 
  <input id="num1" type="text" /> 
</div> 
<div class="field"> 
  <label for="num2">Number 2</label> 
  <input id="num2" type="text" /> 
</div>
```

When "Number 1" is changed, I'd like to change "Number 2" to match it. So this JQuery code:

```
$('#num1').change(function() {
  var one = this.val();
  $('#num2').val(one);
});
```

but it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'
```

on the line

```
var one = this.val()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is object of your element so it will have all the property which your element have like value ,id etc whereas is val() is available with jQuery object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.val()` is only defined on jQuery objects. `this` returns the DOM object, which does not have this property.

To fix your code:

1. Use `$(this).val()`, or
2. Use `this.value`

Answer (score 4):

`this` is DOM object not jquery object. you can use either `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

```
$('#num1').change(function() {
  var one = $(this).val();
 $('#num2').val(one);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `$(this).val();` instead of `this.val();`

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qUyp2/86/)